# Convert WooCommerce CSV order export from UTF-8 to ANSI

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I use 'WooCommerce Customer/Order CSV Export' plugin and need to convert my CSV order export from UTF-8 to ANSI. I have tried the code snippet below in my functions.php, but with no luck. Could you give me a snippet that would work?

```
// change file format to ANSI
apply_filters( 'wc_customer_order_csv_export_download_content_type', 'Content-Type: text/csv; charset=windows-1252' );
```

With kind regards,

Sjors

Comment: Why do you need ANSI?

Comment: Because it's a requirement from the distributor to deliver orders in CSV with ANSI format.